# Is there a process for munging data from many different formats in RapidMiner?

Tags: etl, rapidminer, data-munging

I'm trying to help my team streamline a data ingestion process that is taking up a substantial amount of time. We receive data in multiple formats and with attributes arranged differently. Is there a way using RapidMiner to create a process that:

- Processes files on a schedule that are dropped into a folder (this
  one I think I know but I'd love tips on this as scheduled processes
  are new to me)
- Automatically identifies input filetype and routes to the correct operator ("Read CSV" for example)
- Recognizes a relatively small number of attributes and arranges them accordingly. In some cases, attributes are named the same way as our ingestion format and in others they are not (**phone** vs **phone #** vs **Phone** for example)

The attributes we process mostly consist of **name**, **id**, **phone**, **email**, **address**. Also, in some cases names are split first/last and in some they are full name.

I recognize that munging files for such simple attributes shouldn't be that hard but the number of files we receive and lack of order makes it very difficult to streamline a process without a bit of automation. I'm also going to move to a standardized receiving format but for a number of reasons that's on the horizon and not an immediate solution.

I appreciate any tips or guidance you can share.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is relative broad, so unfortunately I can't give you complete answer. But here are some ideas on how I would tackle the points you mentioned:

- For a full process scheduling RapidMiner Server is what you are
  looking for. In that case you can either define a schedule (e.g.,
  check regularly for new files) or even define a web service to
  trigger the process.
- For selecting the correct operator depending on file type, you could
  use a combination of "Loop Files" and macro extraction to get the
  correct type and the use either "Branch" or "Select Subprocess" for
  switching to different input routes.
- The "Select Attributes" operator has some very powerful options to
  select specific subsets only. In your example I would go for a
  regular expression akin to `[pP]hone.*` to get the different spelling
  variants. Also very helpful in that case would be the "Reorder
  Attributes" operator and "Rename by Replacing" to create a common
  naming schema.

A general tip when building more complex process pipelines is to organize your different tasks in [sub-processes](https://academy.rapidminer.com/learn/video/hints-subprocesses) and use the "Execute Process" operator. This makes everything much more readable and maintainable. Also a good [error handling](https://academy.rapidminer.com/learn/video/error-and-exception-handling) strategy is important to handle unforeseen data formats.

For more elaborate answers and tips from many adavanced RapidMiner users, I also highly recommend the [RapidMiner community](https://community.rapidminer.com/).

I hope this gives a good starting point for your project.

Comment: Hi Robert1er, I would recommend to ask at the RapidMiner community (www.community.rapidminer.com) for specific solutions. The Unicorns there are always eager to help.